# Why child object doesn't have parent method using the module pattern?

Tags: javascript

```
Parent = (function() {
    var parent = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };

    parent.prototype.dostuff = function() {
      console.log(this.name);  
    };

    parent.prototype.more = function() {
      console.log("this should be available on both ... " + this.name);  
    };

    return parent;
}());

Child = (function() {
    var child = function(name) {
        Parent.call(this, name);
        this.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    };

    child.prototype.dostuff = function() {
      console.log("the child class ... " + this.name);
    };

    child.prototype.special = function() {
      console.log("only the child has this method");
    };

    return child;
}());
```

In the above my parent object has a method called "more" but when I new up the child like so .. I can't call the more method unless I prototype it out manually. What am I missing in the above that would enable me to get prototyped methods for free?

```
var first = new Parent("father");
var last = new Child("son");
```

**Update with working jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/kz7Xk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting prototype on the instance, you should set it on the function itself.

`this` in the constructor function refers to the object itself when you create the object with `new`.  But prototype is a property on a function thats used as a constructor, not on the instances.

So you want something like this:

```
Child = (function() {
    var child = function(name) {
        Parent.call(this, name);
    };

    child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

    child.prototype.dostuff = function() {
      console.log("the child class ... " + this.name);
    };

    child.prototype.special = function() {
      console.log("only the child has this method");
    };

    return child;
}());
```

The prototype of Child is set to a new object with parent's prototype on its prototype, allowing it to inherit everything.

Comment: world record -whoa that was fast :)

Comment: Shouldn't you add `new`? You know: `Child = new (function() { ... }())`.

Comment: I think new is another option instead of Object.create (another SO question talks about the pros/cons of both)

Comment: @ToranBillups : If I'm not mistaken, it's required to use the `prototype`, but I suppose you wouldn't be able to use it for an object with an anonymous constructor anyway.

Comment: @Sortofabeginner the way this is currently set up you would end up using new with Child, not inside the module.  He has that in the question above.